# How to use Android Emulator on M1 Mac?

Tags: android-studio, apple-m1

I'm not able to get an Android app to launch in the Emulator on an M1 Mac.

I've very carefully followed instructions for setting up an arm-based emulator instead of x86.

The only arm images that will run on my computer are the ones marked "Release S". With these images, I can create an emulator that I can open manually. However, when I use the Run button in Android Studio, it will not launch my app on the emulator.

Every other arm-based emulator I tried will not even launch: they open to a black window and nothing else happens.

Why is this not working and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'd assume you have looked over (https://medium.com/techiepedia/setting-up-android-emulator-in-m1-mac-fff58ec8bff8) and (https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/my-journey-to-setup-android-emulator-for-m1-macbook-pro-b8365321b3e7)?

Comment: Yes, I read both articles. The first one is about the "preview" emulator that you could install separately. I used that version and it worked for me, but it is obsolete now. I should be able to use the one built in to Android Studio instead.

Comment: @Flarosa did u got the solution yet?? It still says waiting for the device to come online, updated to artic fox now

Comment: @Niraj I installed the "Bumblebee" build of Android Studio (a "Canary" build). The emulator works in this build.